# Prediction interval for AR(1) forecast

Tags: time-series, confidence-interval

[This](https://kevinkotze.github.io/ts-3-forecasting/#fnref1) link (and others, e.g. slides 43 and 46 of [this](https://www.sas.upenn.edu/%7Efdiebold/Teaching104/Ch14_slides.pdf)) say that:

> Where all the coefficients in the model are point estimates, we could calculate the MSE to generate
> distributions for the distribution of future forecast estimates. Note that if we assume that the residuals in the model are,
> $\varepsilon_t \sim$ i. i. d. $\mathcal{N}\left(0,\sigma_{\varepsilon}^2\right)$, it implies that the forecast errors
> should also be normally distributed, $y_{t+h}-\dot{y}_t(h) \sim\mathcal{N}\left(0, \sigma_t(h)\right) $ Such that, $\frac{y_{t+h}-\dot{y}_t(h)}{\sqrt{\dot{\sigma}_t(h)}} \sim
> \mathcal{N}(0,1). $ In this case we could make use of a normal
> distribution, with $z_\alpha$ defining the upper and lower bounds that
> may be used to derive the forecast interval for the $h$-period ahead
> forecast, $ \left[\dot{y}_t(h)-z_{\alpha / 2}
> \sqrt{\dot{\sigma}_t(h)}, \quad \dot{y}_t(h)+z_{\alpha / 2}
> \sqrt{\dot{\sigma}_t(h)}\right]. $ This allows for the construction of
> standard confidence intervals for the parameter estimates, where the
> predictor, $\dot{y}_t(h)$, and the MSE, $\sigma_t(h)$, are used to
> derive the appropriate interval.

However, these forecast intervals estimates don't seem to take into account uncertainty in the *fitted parameters*. Why is this so?

Comment: How are you defining $\hat{\sigma}_t(h)$?

Comment: It seems that the link is defining it as the expected mean squared forecast error: $\mathbb{E}[(y_{t+h}-y_t(h))^2].$